# Dynamically place index in Swift

Tags: arrays, dynamic, indexing, find

How do I take the following code and display the result "white" by using the index returned from "find"?

```
var colors: [String] = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "white"]
var pickAColor2 = "white"
find(colors, "\(pickAColor2)")?
```

I'm looking for something like this to dynamically input the index:

```
color[\(pickAColor2)] // but this doesn't work...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors: [String] = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "white"]
var pickAColor2 = "white"
let index = find(colors, pickAColor2) // index has the value 6
colors[index!] // Returns "white"
```

Make sure to unwrap `index` with `!`.